# Expectation of a random variable uniformly distributed according to another random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let's say $X$ is a random variable with P.D.F. $f_X(x) = 3x^2$ for $0 < x \leq 1$, and $0$ otherwise.
>
> Further, $Y$ is a random variable distributed uniformly on $[0, X]$. Find $E[Y]$

I'm inclined here to just ignore $X$ and treat $Y$ as a random variable on $[0,3]$, but I feel like the answer should depend on $x$. Any suggestions here?

> Finally, $ \displaystyle \Pr(Z \leq z_0 | Y=y, X-x) = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{z_0}exp\left(-\frac{(z-y)^2}{2x^2}\right)dz$ for $0 < y\leq x\leq 1$, and $0$ otherwise. Find $E[Z|X=x]$ and $E[Z^2|X=x]$.

I'm really not sure where to get started on this one.

Comment: Please either ask one question per post, or explain why you believe the questions are sufficiently related to treat them in a single post. Also, note that when you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets that as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats it accordingly. To get the appropriate font and spacing, you can use predefined commands like `\exp`, or, if you need an operator name for which there isn't a predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the law of double expectation (or whatever name you might know it by) one has
$$
  \mathbb{E}[Y] 
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]
= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{2}\right]
= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 x(3x^2) dx
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4}
= \frac{3}{8}.
$$

For the second part of the question (I assume the minus sign to the right of the | bar is meant to be an equals sign) note that the density $f_{Z|X,Y}$ of $Z$ given $X,Y$ is Normal($Y,X^2$). Then 
$$
  f_{Z|X}(z|x) 
= \int_0^x f_{Z,Y|X}(z,y|x) dy 
= \int_0^x f_{Z|X,Y}(z|y,x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)dy
= \int_0^x \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{(z-y)^2}{2x^2}\right)dy
$$
since the density for $Y|X$ is $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{1}{x} \chi\{ 0 < y < x\}$.
Then
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E}[Z|X=x]
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty z f_{Z|X}(z|x)dz \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty z \int_0^x  \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{2\pi}}
   \exp\left( -\frac{(z-y)^2}{2x^2}\right)dydz \\
&= \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \int_{-\infty}^\infty z \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}
   \exp\left( -\frac{(z-y)^2}{2x^2}\right)dzdy \\
&= \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x  y dy \\
&= \frac{1}{2}x
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E}[Z^2|X = x]
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2 f_{Z|X}(z|x)dz \\
&= \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2 \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}
   \exp\left( -\frac{(z-y)^2}{2x^2}\right)dzdy \\
&= \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x (x^2 + y^2)dy \\
&= x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^2 \\
&= \frac{4}{3}x^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Since $Z$ conditionally on $(X,Y)$ is normal with mean $Y$ and variance $X^2$, one has $E[Z\mid X,Y]=Y$ hence $E[Z\mid X]=E[Y\mid X]=\frac12X$ (not $\frac12X^2$). Likewise, $E[Z^2\mid X,Y]=Y^2+X^2$ hence $E[Z^2\mid X]=E[Y^2\mid X]+X^2=\frac43X^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Had the density of $Y$ as uniform(0,1) instead of uniform(0,x). Edited my answer

Comment: Good. (But I am not sure that delving into the details of gaussian densities yields the most illuminating answer. All that which counts is that, conditionally on X, Y is distributed as XU with E[U]=1/2, E[U^2]=1/3 and U independent of Y, and that conditionally on (X,Y), Z is distributed as Y+XT, with E[T]=0, E[T^2]=1 and T independent of (X,Y).)